# How should I restructure this event-handling code?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I've been reading some C++ books (Sutters, Meyers) lately which motivated me to start using smart pointers (and object destruction in general) more effectively. But now I'm not sure how to fix what I have.
Specifically, I now have a IntroScene class which inherits from both Scene and InputListener.

Scene isn't really relevant, but the InputListener subscribes to an InputManager on construction,
and unsubs again on destruction.

```
class IntroScene : public sfg::Scene, public sfg::InputListener {
/*structors, inherited methods*/
virtual bool OnEvent(sf::Event&) override; //inputlistener
}
```

But now, if the inputmanager sends events over to a scene, and the scene decided to replace itself
because of it, I have function running on an object that no longer exists.

```
bool IntroScene::OnEvent(sf::Event& a_Event) {
    if (a_Event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed) {
        sfg::Game::Get()->SceneMgr()->Replace(ScenePtr(new IntroScene()));
    } //here the returned smartpointer kills the scene/listener
}
```

Side-question: Does that matter? I googled it but did not find a definite yes or no. I do know 100% 
no methods are invoked on the destroyed object after it is destroyed.
I can store the Replace() return value until the end of the OnEvent() method if I have to.

The real problem is InputListener

```
InputListener::InputListener() {
    Game::Get()->InputMgr()->Subscribe(this);
}

InputListener::~InputListener() {
    if (m_Manager) m_Manager->Unsubscribe(this);
}
```

since it is called during OnEvent(), which is called by InputManager during HandleEvents()

```
void InputManager::HandleEvents(EventQueue& a_Events) const {
    while (!a_Events.empty()) {
        sf::Event& e = a_Events.front();
        for (auto& listener : m_Listeners) {
            if (listener->OnEvent(e)) //swallow event
                break;
        }
        a_Events.pop();
    }

void InputManager::Subscribe(InputListener* a_Listener) {
    m_Listeners.insert(a_Listener);
    a_Listener->m_Manager = this;
}

void InputManager::Unsubscribe(InputListener* a_Listener) {
    m_Listeners.erase(a_Listener);
    a_Listener->m_Manager = nullptr;
}
```

So when the new Scene+Listener is created, and when the old one is destroyed, the list m_Listeners is modified during the loop. So the thing breaks.
I've thought about setting a flag when starting and stopping the loop, and storing (un)subscriptions that happen while it is set in a separate list, and handle that after. But it feels a bit hacky.

So, how can I actually redesign this properly to prevent these kind of situations? Thanks in advance.

EDIT, Solution:
I ended up going with the loop flags and deferred entry list (inetknight's answer below)
for subscription only, since that can be safely done later.

Unsubscriptions have to be dealt with immediately, so instead of storing raw pointers I store a (pointer-mutable bool) pair (mutable since a set only returns a const_iterator). I set the bool to false when that happens and check for it in the event loop (see dave's comment below).
Not sure it's cleanest possible solution, but it works like a charm. Thanks a lot guys

Comment: My answer is exactly what you stated you'd already thought of. What is it which makes you think it's hacky though?

Comment: null out the listener in unsubscribe and let the HandleEvents loop erase elements which are null. This can also be done by storing weak_ptrs in InputManager for the listeners and trying to lock before calling OnEvent. This way it doesn't hurt your loop traversal but the effect of unsubscribing is immediate.

Comment: It feels a hacky because it's written specifically to fix something I overlooked when I so poorly 'designed' this thing. In addition, a scene can contain other listeners who'll get destroyed with it, but who might still be send events via the loop (since the listener-list does not use smart pointers, since that would make the listeners' destructo useless). So the unsub has to be immediate, or referenced objects have to be kept intact until after the loop as well. This only just occurred to me however, and is not in the OP.

Comment: @Dave I'm not sure if I can use weak_ptr here since the shared_ptr is of type Scene, the other base. The listeners are in a set, since they should both be unique and ordered, so nulling them might throw that off.
I'll try to use the pointer-bool pair in the list instead, set the bool on unsubscription and check it before OnEvent. I'm pretty sure I'm not overlooking something this way. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Side-question: Does that matter? I googled it but did not find a definite yes or no. I do know 100% no methods are invoked on the destroyed object after it is destroyed. I can store the Replace() return value until the end of the OnEvent() method if I have to.

If you know 100% no methods are invoked ont he destroyed object and none of its member variables are accessed, then it's *safe*. Whether or not it's *intended* is up to you.

You could have another list of objects which have requested to be un/subscribed. Then after you've told everyone in the list of events, you would then process the list of un/subscription requests before continuing on to the next event.

```
/* this should be a member of InputManager however you did not provide a class definition */
typedef std::pair<InputListener *, bool> SubscriptionRequest;
bool handleEventsActive = false;
std::vector<SubscriptionRequest> deferredSubscriptionRequests;

void InputManager::HandleEvents(EventQueue& a_Events) const {
    // process events
    handleEventsActive = true;
    while (!a_Events.empty()) {
        sf::Event& e = a_Events.front();
        for (auto& listener : m_Listeners)
        {
            //swallow event
            if (listener->OnEvent(e)) {
                break;
            }
        }
        a_Events.pop();

        // process deferred subscription requests occurred during event
        while ( not deferredSubscriptionRequests.empty() ) {
            SubscriptionRequest request = deferredSubscriptionRequests.back();
            deferredSubscriptionRequests.pop_back();
            DoSubscriptionRequest(request);
        }
    }
    handleEventsActive = false;
}
void InputManager::DoSubscriptionRequest(SubscriptionRequest &request) {
    if ( request.second ) {
        m_Listeners.insert(request.first);
        request.first->m_Manager = this;
    } else {
        m_Listeners.erase(request.first);
        request.first->m_Manager = nullptr;
    }
}

void InputManager::Subscribe(InputListener* a_Listener)
{
    SubscriptionRequest request{a_Listener, true};
    if ( handleEventsActive ) {
        deferredSubscriptionRequests.push_back(request);
    } else {
        DoSubscriptionRequest(request);
    }
}

void InputManager::Unsubscribe(InputListener* a_Listener)
{
    SubscriptionRequest request{a_Listener, false};
    if ( handleEventsActive ) {
        deferredSubscriptionRequests.push_back(request);
    } else {
        DoSubscriptionRequest(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I described this in the last alinea though, it feels a bit contrived, like a bandaid-fix. I was hoping this entire problem could be avoided rather than remedied. I'll await some further insights, before I go with this.